# Google cloud app engine 1 hour latency without notivceable response times

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

I've got a GAE nodejs flex socek.io + express web and websocket server...

Everything works just fine and response times are really good but when i go to the metrics tab i can see this for latency
[image: GAE latency tab]

an hour latency??? I'm guessing it's something related to socket.io long polling? or websockets themselves?

Anybody cares to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related with the time alive of your sockets, which seems to be 60 mins. I guess you are using sessions for your app. In this case, that you are using [socket.io](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#session_affinity), it fall back on HTTP long polling, just as you mentioned. To get a better performance there is a new [`session affinity`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#network_settings) setting in the `app.yaml`. You can take a look into it.

If your app is working just fine just keep monitoring your Memory usage and CPU usage. Always try to keep a good management of your resources.

Comment: Note that session affinity is only relevant if you are using multiple instances.
From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#session_affinity)